# How to get HTTP header (Content-Type) from URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Good afternoon! Here is what I am trying to achieve.

I have an input which allow the user to enter an URL (mostly for images) but it can also be a different type of file. I am searching for a way to verify that the url exists and also get the mime type.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2jf74dm/) of my javascript tests.

I found a way to do it using a PHP and AJAX with a function like that:

PHP:

```
function get_url_content_type( $url ) {

    $header = get_headers( $url, 1 );

    if ( isset( $header['Content-Type'] ) ) {

        return $header['Content-Type'];
    }
}
```

I am not sure that is the right way to do it, does anyone have better ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: so this works fine and well?

Comment: Yes it works but I am not comfortable with the fact that I have to make an AJAX call to my server to get the remote HTTP header. I just wanted to know if someone was aware of a way to do it directly with Javascript.

Comment: i don't know if you can directly, because its not your own domain

Comment: Yeah that's what I am guessing, I tried with "jsonp" but I am not familiar with it and it was not working very well.

Comment: will you have access to the destination server? That way you could enable CORS for the request domain. BTW, why do you need to get the content type of a png image response ? It will be "image/png"

Comment: No I will not have access to the server. The user can enter any URL, if the url does not exist I display an error, if this is an image I generate a preview, if the file is a PDF I display an other preview etc...

Comment: Can you use a plugin like this one?: http://markserbol.github.io/urlive/ (anyway for pdf you will need to download the file to generate a preview)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will already convert the response based on the content type (check this [url](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/ajax.js#L662) for details) if you dont specify a `type` on the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call.

So all you can do is check the type of the generated response, to deduce the Content-Type that was sent:

```
$.get("myPage.html", { }, function(data) {
  if(typeof(data) === "string") {
    //html
  } else {
    //JSON
  }
});
```

In this case, it doesn't work because google explicitly disables Cross-Origin Request on its hosted images. If you run your tests with Firebug enabled, you will get the message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

However, enabling CORS will need some work at server side that I don't think google is willing to do.

**EDIT:**

If you want to generate a client-side preview of some files, try using something like:

- https://github.com/markserbol/urlive